# how to calculate timecode(hh:mm:ss:frame) to milliseconds or seconds in bash script or python

Tags: python, bash, milliseconds, seconds

i have tried many times for this calculation . but not sure what difference ..
for example , 1000ms / 29.97 = 1frame around 33ms (more precisely : 0.03336s)based on this rule , if calculate  09:30:58;11 frames to seconds then,i could have get 34256.363s ,but other caculation tool gave me 34256.388s

```
#!/bin/bash
hours=9
min=30
sec=56
frame=11
totalseconds=$(echo "scale=1; ($hours*60*60)+($min*60)+($sec)+($frame*0.033)" | bc -l)
echo $totalseconds
```

i have no idea what difference ??

Comment: I cannot confirm this. My output is 34256.363 which is correct.

Comment: and what are your other calculation tools ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you mention what other tools you used and what input you provided.

Comment: sorry .video start timecode is   not 09:30:58;11  but . 09:30:56;11, result is same 34256 part , but problem is 11frames .. apple fcp do calculate   34256.388 ,
but i have no idea how to do apple  .388 ??
below web calculation tool also gave me .388 
http://www.michaelcinquin.com/tools/timecode_keykode

Comment: @29.97 : 09:30:58:11 (1026725 images = 34258.390833 seconds 
= 1644402760 samples @48Khz)

Comment: @29.97 : 09:30:56:11 (1026665 images = 34256.388833 seconds 
= 1644306664 samples @48Khz)

Comment: problem is 56seconds , 56*29.97 = 1678.32 , but that tools gave me 1680images(frames)  what the fuck this :-)  ?

Comment: finally i had got it !!  thanks